# With multiple Google accounts logged in, use only one account for Google Maps

Tags: google-account, google-maps

I have several Google accounts on my phone. I want to use only *one* of those with Google Maps. I must have accidentally used another one a few times, and now I keep getting notifications about it, should I do some more reviews and whatever.

I've tried time and again and never managed to come any close to disabling Maps for some specific accounts without removing the account altogether from the phone

Is there a way?

Comment: The original question was how to REMOVE the account. After @andrew T edit, the answer makes sense, but that is not and answer to the original question.

Comment: @DGaleano there's [an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221335/44325) that says it's impossible. It was deleted (perhaps mistakenly), but I undeleted it just now because that's the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. I also want the same. There is no way to stop some accounts to appear in Google maps (or any other apps like contacts). It is very frustrating but unfortunately there will not be any solution for this issue from Google. So you are kinda stuck.

Comment: I agree. This answers the original question about "REMOVE" the account from maps.

Answer (score 1):

Even I've multiple accounts logged-in on my phone.
You can follow [this Google's guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3118687?hl=en) to disable the location history for a particular account on all devices or on a specific devices.

Turn Location History on or off
You can turn off Location History for your account at any time. If you use a work or school account, your administrator needs to make this setting available for you. If they do, you'll be able to use Location History as any other user.

Go to the "[Location History](https://myactivity.google.com/activitycontrols?settings=location)" section of your Google Account.
Choose whether your account or your devices can report Location History to Google.
Your account and all devices: At the top, turn Location History on or off.
Only a certain device: Under "This device" or "Devices on this account," turn the device on or off.

Comment: The original question was how to REMOVE the account. After @andrew T edit, the answer makes sense, but that is not an answer to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow [the steps](https://support.google.com/android/answer/7664951?hl=en) below, they might help:

> 1. Open your phone's Settings app.
> 2. Tap Accounts. If you don't see "Accounts," tap Users & accounts.
> 3. Tap the account you want to remove And then Remove account.
> 4. If this is the only Google Account on the phone, you'll need to enter your phone's pattern, PIN, or password for security.
>
> Important: Settings can vary by phone. For more info, contact your device manufacturer.

Comment: The OP didn't want to remove the account completely: "*without removing the account altogether from the phone.*"